# What does qqnorm do in R?

Tags: r, static, normal-distribution

I executed the following code in the R console:

```
> y = seq(-4,4, length=100)
> x = dnorm(y)
> plot(x)
> qqnorm(x)
```

The plot shows a normal distribution for `x`:
[image]

and the output of `qqnorm` is:
[image]

I've read in many sources and video tutorials that `qqnorm` is used to check if a distribution is normal and when the distribution is normal, the plot is close to a straight line, but the output above shows something opposite. So, I'm confused what actually `qqnorm` does!

Comment: Look at plots from `plot(linearmodel)`. You'll see a plot that can be produced with `qqnorm` and `qqline`.

Comment: qq stays for quantile-quantile norm for normal.  
The function lets you compare your quantiles againts normal ones.  
If your data a "truly" normal all points will lay on the diagonal.  
On your second plot, your distribution tails are far away from normal distribution quantiles

Answer (score 1):

you are confusing two things.

1. What you are looking at is the probability density function (pdf) of a normal distribution: `x = dnorm(y)`. `x` does **not** have a normal distribution. `x` only contains the y-values of the normal pdf.
2. The qqplot tells you if a sample was generated by a normal distribution. Try the following:

   set.seed(1);
   z = rnorm(100)

Then `z` contains 100 samples from a standard normal distribution and `qqnorm(z)` should be close to a straight line.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, what the x axis of the second graph tells? -2, -1, 0, 1, 2?

Comment: It's the theoretical quantiles of a standard normal distribution. They can be computed using `qnorm`